# dmatest.ko - how use it?

Tags: c, testing, linux-kernel, dma

I want to initiate a DMA-Transfer for testing.

I stumbled accross a dmatest.c in the kernel sources (drivers/dma). I compiled a Kernel with this Module and tried it without any params.

```
sudo modprobe dmatest
```

and i get with dmesg

```
__dma_request_channel: fail ((null))
```

What are the prerequisites for dmatest.ko?
Should I load a special DMA-Engine?
Is a special param for dmatest.ko required (default should probe anything!?)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can refer to https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/dmatest.txt for guide.

Certainly, you should run a DMA-Engine (module or built-in) before dmatest, there are a lot of DMA Controller driver under drivers/dma/, such as amba-pl08x.c, dw_dmac.c, pl330.c and so on.

You can use command "ls -1 /sys/class/dma/" to print the available channel lists.